# How ro autostart shell script with xprofile?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, archlinux

I'm learning how to shell script and so I wrote myself a small script which changes my wallpaper based on time of the day, I want to run it on start up but adding it to `.xprofile` like this `wallchanger &` doesn't work, it just doesn't start up. I'm using Archlabs (based on Arch) with LightDM and bspwm (adding it to `bspwmrc` also didn't work)

Comment: `.xprofile` is not always sourced automatically and depends on how you start Xorg. Do you use `startx` after logging in on console or do you login using XDM/GDM/LightDM?

Comment: @blami I use LightDM

Comment: Is your `.xprofile` executable (`chmod +x ~/.xprofile`) and does it have appropriate shebang as frist line (e.g. `#!/bin/sh` or whatever shell you want it to be interpreted in)?

Comment: @blami sorry for the supper late reply. I did make the `.xprofile` executable but that didn't change anything

Comment: that's weird, when you look into `/etc/lightdm/Xsession` do you see `.xprofile` sourced from there?

Comment: @blami yes, it's there, even for the correct directory and everything

Comment: Just for reference, any file that is `source`'d (bash) or `.`'ed (dot'ed i.e. the posix equivalent) needs _neither_ a shebang _nor_ an executable mode bit.

Answer (score 1):

I have this systemd unit which changes wallpapers using *feh*.

```html
[Unit]
Description=Set random wallpaper

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment="walls_dir=%h/pix/wall/collection"
Environment="walls_cmd=/usr/bin/feh --bg-fill"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'find -L "$walls_dir" -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.png" \) -print0 | shuf -n1 -z | xargs -0 $walls_cmd'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and here is wallpaper.timer

```html
[Unit]
Description=Random wallpaper with feh

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=5m
Unit=wallpaper.service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```